Can't install apk using adb
guys!
I want to create a simple HelloWorld apk in C using raylib.
My project structure:
HelloWorld/
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── src/
    │   ├── main.c
    ├── android/
    │   └── AndroidManifest.xml
    └── build/

src/main.c:
#include <raylib.h>

int main(void) {
    InitWindow(800, 600, "My App");

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
        DrawText("Hello, World!", 190, 200, 20, LIGHTGRAY);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
}

CMakeLists.txt:
# Minimun version of CMake required to build the project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# Define the project name
project(HelloWorld)

# Specify the path of raylib headers
include_directories($ENV{RAYLIB_ANDROID}/include)        

# Compile C code into a shared library
add_library(hello_world SHARED src/main.c)

# Import raylib
add_library(raylib STATIC IMPORTED)

# Specify the path of raylib
set_target_properties(raylib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION $ENV{RAYLIB_ANDROID}/lib/arm64/libraylib.a)

# Link with necessary libraries
target_link_libraries(hello_world raylib android log EGL GLESv2)

android/AndroidManifest.txt:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.oussamateyib.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="35" />

    <application android:label="Hello World">
        <activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
            android:label="Hello World"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:exported="true">

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="hello_world" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

In build/:
I run:
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%ANDROID_NDK_HOME%\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-35 ..
make

--> libhello_world.so is generated successfully and i copied it to subdirectory lib/arm64-v8a.
Then i run:
aapt package -f -m -F HelloWorld-temp.apk -M ../android/AndroidManifest.xml -I %ANDROID_HOME%/platforms/android-35/android.jar

aapt add HelloWorld-temp.apk lib/arm64-v8a/libhello_world.so

--> apk is packaged successfully
Then i run:
zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-temp.apk 
HelloWorld.apk

--> apk is aligned successfully
Then i run:
apksigner sign --ks my-key.jks --ks-key-alias HelloWorld HelloWorld.apk

--> apk is signed successfully with my previously generated key.
Then i run (with my phone connected via usb):
adb install HelloWorld.apk

Output:
Performing Incremental Install
Serving...
All files should be loaded. Notifying the device.
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Scanning Failed.: Package /data/app/~~KjqkABJbYD3SKFrJm_qwcQ==/com.oussamateyib.helloworld-rmQUIQxHLXKSuzm4eo3fuw==/base.apk code is missing]

--> ???
Any idea?
Note: my phone abi is indeed arm64-v8a.

Your AndroidManifest.xml is missing an important entry: android:hasCode. For APK files that do not contain DEX code (thus don't have a classes.dex file) you have to set android:hasCode="false" in the <application> tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Whether the application contains any DEX code—that is, code using the
Kotlin or Java programming language. It's "true" if it does and
"false" if not. When the value is "false", the system doesn't try to
load any application code when launching components. The default value
is "true". If the application includes native (C/C++) code, but no DEX
code, this should be set to "false". If set to "true" when the APK
contains no DEX code, the app may fail to load.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#code

Thank you. The app has been installed successfully. But I have encountered another problem, the app crashes right after opening it! Why?

@OussamaTeyib Make sure your .so files are stored uncompressed in the ZIP/APK file. Recent versions don't extract .so files but load them directly from within the APK file. Alternatively you can try to set extractNativeLibs=true in AndroidManifest.xml. Another reason is may be because you only have a main method but Android requires a special android_main. See ndk example how to do it correct: https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na

I tried using android_main() instead of main(), but I encountered a duplicate symbol error during the build process, as android_main() is already defined in the raylib core library.
I also checked that the .so files are stored uncompressed in the APK and added the extractNativeLibs=true attribute to my AndroidManifest.xml, but the issue persists.

@OussamaTeyib Please look at the linked example project at github. The android_main method requires a special parameter.

I updated the source code to include the header and used void android_main(struct android_app* state). I also updated *CMakeLists to build the native_apo_glue library add_library(native_app_glue STATIC C:/Programs/Android/SDK/ndk/27.0.12077973/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c) and linked hello_world with it. Then, i run: `make
ld.lld: error: duplicate symbol: android_main



defined at main.c:4
defined at rcore.c
rcore.o:(.text.android_main+0x0) in archive /libraylib.a`



